# Calling an SSIS package with SQL without using a job and specifying who the SSIS package will run as

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to run an SSIS package using a stored procedure without using a job so that I can call multiple instances of the package without getting the job still in use error should multiple people want to use it at once. I've used the create and start execution procedures in the SSIS database which I have working but I also need the package to inherit the permissions of the person calling the procedure in order for it move some files during it's execution.

So far I'm using SELECT suser_name() to get the profile name of the person calling the procedure but I'm not sure where to use that next, will execute as follow through into the SSIS package if I run the start_execute procedure using it?

Comment: I have used this for testing permissions, you execute as a user, you can try something like this:  EXECUTE AS USER = 'IDToRunAs';  
--Display current execution context.  
SELECT SUSER_NAME(), USER_NAME();  

Execute SPhere

Comment: But why do you need to run as the persons ID?  If you know anyone who will run this is allowed to move the files, create a permissions group that has all the access to exeucte the job and access the files, then grant the users access to that role.